# IIS 6 smtp messages stuck in inetpub/mailroot/queue

Tags: smtp, iis-6

When I try to send emails to domains like yahoo.com, msn.com.... I see that the messages are stored in inetpub/mailroot/queue and are not forwarded to the corresponding addresses.

I set authentication not required, and in the relay tab I selected allow computers which succesfully authenticate to relay...

My question is: why remain the messages in ../queue? Ho can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing similar problem for a few days, at last I stopped the smtp, cleared the queue, and re-start the smtp again. Now seems it is working.